# UnPublish app not available to select in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to un-publish an app in play console but the un-publish checkbox is disabled. I just can't select the un-publish option.

Quick help would be highly appreciated. Below is attached screenshot of settings section.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @[PineapplePie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19580355/pineapplepie) comment i was able to un-publish the app. App had managed publishing on. After turning off managed publishing i was able to un-publish the app.

**Following was the problem**
[image]

**Solution:**

Turn off managed publishing in
`Publishing overview -> Managed publishing status`

[image]

**Note:**

After un-publishing the app i again tried to enable managed publishing but it gave following error message
[image]

The same applies for un-publishing the app if you have managed publishing on

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859350#unpublish):

Before you can unpublish an app, you must ensure that:

You have accepted the latest Developer Distribution Agreement.
Your app has no errors that need to be addressed, such as failing to fill in the content rating questionnaire or provide details about your app's target audience and content.
Managed publishing is not active for the app that you want to unpublish.

Comment: Thanks @PineapplePie. App has no such issues as you mentioned.

Comment: @AttiqueUrRehman hmm, interesting. Are you sure that managed publishing is turned off? It's usually turned on. Just in case, Publishing overview -> Managed publishing status

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. I had managed publishing on thats why un-publish checkbox was disabled. Turning off managed publishing solved the problem.

Comment: @AttiqueUrRehman, great news! I'll be glad then, if you can accept my answer ;)